# Editar documento doc(x) con node.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, docx

Estoy intentando hacer que los datos recogidos del usuario se envíen a un documento de texto doc(x) guardado en un servidor, de modo que dichos datos completen una plantilla.
Hasta ahora sólo he encontrado una API de Office para JavaScript, pero me preocupa que tenga problemas de compatibilidad o permisos.

¿Existe algún modo de introducir los parámetros recogidos en un documento sin necesidad de utilizar dicha API?

La idea no es almacenar simplemente los parámetros en un doc, sino que se almacenen en espacios concretos de un documento existente.

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería que el documento tenga, en lugar de espacios en blanco, *nombres de variables predefinidas*. En este caso, me imagino una solución más factible, como leer el documento y con una librería de templating reemplazar los *nombres de variables* del documento con variables reales pasadas por un objeto por ejemplo, para finalmente sobreescribir el fichero.

Comment: Gracias Gustavo, no tengo mucho conocimiento de librerías de templating, ¿quizás Moustache?, he tratado de modificar el documento con el módulo fs de node.js, pero sólo me permite interactuar con archivos de texto plano (txt)

Comment: Disculpa la demora, Pablo. Hay un paquete para esto último muy usado por otras bibliotecas; se llama [string-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template).

Comment: ¿Cuál fue la API que encontraste? Cabe mencionar que Microsoft Word tiene la capacidad de crear formularios y de insertar campos para mostrar propiedades tanto incluidas (built-in] como personalizadas, sin embargo, no todos los editores que archivos doc(x) pueden manejarlos. ¿Estás buscando que sea editable por cualquier editor de texto o sólo te interesa Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hago un ejemplo de como lo realizo yo actualmente y la web del autor. Esto es un servicio al que llamo pasándole el json con las claves que quiero remplazar y la ruta al archivo .docx que tengo como platilla.

Dependencias

```
{
    "docxtemplater": "^3.6.3",
    "jszip": "^2.6.1"
}
```

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#simple

Un saludo, espero que te sirva

```js
var JSZip = require('jszip');
var Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = getDoc = function (data, file) {
    // Cargo el docx como un  binary
    var content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve( file), 'binary');

    var zip = new JSZip(content);

    var doc = new Docxtemplater();
    doc.loadZip(zip);

    // setea los valores de data ej: { first_name: 'John' , last_name: 'Doe'}
    doc.setData(data);

    try {
        // renderiza el documento (remplaza las ocurrencias como {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
        doc.render();
    }
    catch (error) {
        var e = {
            message: error.message,
            name: error.name,
            stack: error.stack,
            properties: error.properties,
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ error: e }));
        throw error;
    }

    var buffer = doc.getZip()
        .generate({ type: 'nodebuffer' });

    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve('tmpdocs', data.doc + file), buffer);

    return path.resolve(__dirname.replace('tmpdocs', data.doc + file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias librerías javascript bien sólo para el navegador, sólo para node o usables en ambos sistemas que te permiten manipular, interactuar o usar ficheros docx a modo de templates.

Por ejemplo (comentarios a Septiembre de 2018):

- [DOCX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js). Que está muy desactualizada y probablemente no funcione correctamente.
- [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js). Que permite convertir un documento html a docx.
- [officegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen). Una librería para node (con planes de que funcione [en el navegador](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen/issues/126)) que permite generar ficheros en distintos formatos de MS-Office.
- [docx-template](https://github.com/lalalic/docx-template). Permite usar ficheros docx como template y rellenarlo con variables js.
- [docx-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-templates). Permite usar ficheros docx como template y rellenarlo con variables js.
- [generate-docx](https://github.com/telemark/generate-docx). Sólo nodejs, no funciona en el navegador. Permite usar ficheros docx como template y rellenarlo con variables js. En realidad es un wrapper de docxtemplater del que faltan muchas de sus características como [incluir imágenes](https://github.com/telemark/generate-docx/issues/20). Aporta muy poquito sobre docxtemplater.
- [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/).  Permite usar ficheros docx como template y rellenarlo con variables js.

De estas librerías yo sólo he probado [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/) y la estamos usando en producción en varios proyectos. Es Software Libre con algunos plugins de pago y permite por ejemplo incluír imágenes.

Comment: La preguntas trata acerca de no usar la librería que encontró el OP luego es lógico pensar que quiere usar "JavaScript puro", es decir, sin librerías de terceros.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Ruben, pero bueno, no estoy seguro de lo que quiere el OP y no especifica que no quiera usar librerías, si no que no quiere usar una API en concreto. En mi experiencia modificar ficheros docx o xlsx sin el empleo de una librería es posible, pero un verdadero dolor de cabeza. Tiene que haber un motivo muy poderoso para una usar una librería para este tipo de tarea.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que hacer editar archivos como los de Office sin usar un librería es un dolor de cabeza. Punto a parte de la que la pregunta no es del todo clara, la respuesta es una lista de cosas pero el modelo del sitio no es adecuado para discutir sobre ellas, de hecho no se permiten las preguntas sobre listas de cosas. Me parece que deberías centrar tu respuesta en la librería que conoces y en cómo usarla, claro, sin extenderte demasiado, en particular porque el OP podría editar su pregunta para hacer la más clara.

Comment: amigo no sabes si docxtemplater soporta archivos formato .doc? (word 97-2003)

Comment: encuentro que la respuesta de @FranciscoPuga esta correcta, ya que no solamente da respuesta al OP sino que le explica todas las posibilidades que tiene para realizar dicha tarea detallando cada una de estas.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Existe algún modo de introducir los parámetros recogidos en un documento sin necesidad de utilizar dicha API?

## Respuesta corta

Asumiendo que por doc(x) te refieres a un archivo .doc o .docx, sí es posible pero generalmente no tiene sentido "reinventar la rueda".

## Explicación

El formato .doc es un formato binario, el formato .docx es un formato "compuesto", ya que es un archivo comprimido que incluye varios archivos de los cuales los principales son archivos XML y el resto son recursos, por ejemplo, imágenes.

Por otro lado las librerías de JavaScript lo que hace es ahorrarte trabajo, pero uno debería dedicar tiempo a conocer su enfoque y alcances.

Si insistes en usar JavaScript puro y asumiendo te decides por usar .docx, lo siguiente es lo que "se me ocurre" sin haber repasado la documentación

- Obtener el archivo .docx y los datos provistos por el usurio
- Descomprimir el archivo .docx y seleccionar el archivo principal.
- Repetir para cada elemento:

  - Si la estructura es conocida, entonces usar seleccionar el elemento e insertar el contenido provisto por el usuario.
  - Si la estructura no es conocida, debe haber un mapa o diccionario que establezca la relación del dato provisto por el usuario con su ubicación en el documento.
- Comprimir los archivos en un nuevo .docx
- Guardar el nuevo archivo .docx

Cabe mencionar que Microsoft Word tiene la capacidad de crear formularios y de insertar campos para mostrar propiedades tanto incluidas (built-in) como personalizadas, proteger el documento y proteger los campos, etc. sin embargo, no todos los editores que archivos .doc y .docx pueden manejar archivos en los que se usa estas características, además que esto podría "complicar" el código pues se deberán considerar esos elementos.